# How to carry master and child data from a kendo hierarchical grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I'm trying to carry both master & child data to the server from a kendo heirarchical grid.

Here is my Grid:

```
//To Define Data Source for Yearly Holiday Kendo Grid
        var YearlyHolidayDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "HLDY_CODE",
                    fields: {
                        HLDY_SLNO: { editable: true },
                        HLDY_DATE: { editable: true },
                        HLDY_DAY: { editable: true },
                        HLDY_NAME: { editable: true },
                        HLDY_TYPE: { editable: true },
                        HLDY_STUS: { editable: true },
                        HLDY_DFIN_TYPE: { editable: true },
                        HLDY_REM: { editable: true }

                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 10

        });

        //To Define Columns for Yearly Holiday Kendo Grid
        var YearlyHolidayGrid = $("#YearlyHolidayGrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: YearlyHolidayDataSource,
            pageable: true,
            editable: true,
            detailInit: detailInit,
            selectable: "row",
            navigatable: true,
            filterable: true,
            sortable: true,
            height: 400,
            columns: [
                  { field: "HLDY_SLNO", title: "SL", width: "50px" },
                  { field: "HLDY_DATE", title: "Date", width: "60px" },
                  { field: "HLDY_DAY", title: "Day", width: "60px" },
                  { field: "HLDY_NAME", title: "Holiday Name", width: "200px", attributes: { "class": "HolidayName"} },
                  { field: "HLDY_TYPE", title: "Holiday Type", width: "90px" },
                  { field: "HLDY_STUS", title: "Holiday Status", width: "80px", editor: YearlyHolidayStatus },
                  { field: "HLDY_DFIN_TYPE", title: "Defined as", width: "70px", editor: YearlyHolidayDefinedAs },
                  { field: "HLDY_REM", title: "Remarks", width: "80px" },
                  { command: [{ name: "DeltedRow", text: "Delete"}], title: "Delete", width: "90px" }
            ]

        });
        var DetailsGrid;
        function detailInit(e) {
             DetailsGrid = $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
                dataSource: SpecialHolidayDataSource,
                pageable: true,
                editable: true,
                selectable: "row",
                navigatable: true,
                filterable: true,
                sortable: true,
                height: 200,
                toolbar: ["create"],
                columns: [
                      { field: "HLDY_SPCL_SLNO", title: "SL", width: "50px" },
                      { field: "HLDY_DATE", title: "Date", width: "100px" },
                      { field: "DIVI_NAME", title: "Division", width: "100px", attributes: { "class": "DivisionName" } },
                      { field: "UNIT_NAME", title: "Unit", width: "100px", attributes: { "class": "UnitName" } },
                      { field: "PLANT_NAME", title: "Plant", width: "100px", attributes: { "class": "PlantName" } },
                      { field: "DEPT_NAME", title: "Department", width: "100px", attributes: { "class": "DepartmentName" } },
                      { field: "SECT_NAME", title: "Section", width: "100px", attributes: { "class": "SectionName" } },
                      { field: "ACTIVE_STATUS", title: "Active Status", width: "100px", editor: ddlActiveInactive },
                      { field: "HLDY_SPCL_REM", title: "Remarks", width: "100px" },
                      { command: [{ name: "DeltedRow", text: "Delete" }], title: "Delete", width: 100 }
                ]
            }).data("kendoGrid");
        }
```

Here is my two javascript object to carry the values.

```
// Java Script object to carry the form data from UI to Server
    var Yearly_Holiday = {"HLDY_SLNO": "", "HLDY_DATE": "", "HLDY_NAME": "", "HLDY_TYPE": "", "HLDY_STUS": "", "HLDY_DFIN_TYPE": "", "HLDY_REM": "", "Special_Holiday": ""};
    var Special_Holiday = { "HLDY_SPCL_SLNO": "", "HLDY_DATE": "", "DIVI_CODE": "", "UNIT_CODE": "", "PLANT_CODE": "", "DEPT_CODE": "", "SECT_CODE": "", "HLDY_SPCL_REM": "", "ActiveStatus": "" };
```

Here is my Code for Save Method:

```
  function Save() {

            if (saveStatus == 0) {
                var MasterDataSource = $("#YearlyHolidayGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
                MasterData = MasterDataSource.data(); // Get Master Grid Data

                var ChildDataSource = DetailsGrid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
                ChildData = ChildDataSource.data(); // Get Detail Grid Data

                Yearly_Holiday.Special_Holiday = [];

                Yearly_Holiday.CrudStatus = $("#CrudStatus").val();


                for (var i = MasterData.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    Yearly_Holiday.HLDY_DATE = MasterData[i].HLDY_DATE;
                    Special_Holiday.DIVI_CODE = ChildData[i].DIVI_CODE;
                        Yearly_Holiday.Special_Holiday.push(Special_Holiday);
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/HRMC_HDL01/HRMF_HDL01',
                        data: JSON.stringify(Yearly_Holiday),
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json;',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (response) {

                        }
                    });
            }

    };
```

I can read the master values but not the detail values.

Comment: what do you mean you can't read details value ?  `ChildDataSource.data()` returns nothing right ?

Comment: Yes, I need to find a way to fetch the child data.

Comment: you should add some more explanation about your expectations and what you see instead; did you try debugging and what were the results? lastly: you increase your chances of getting an answer by copying all of this into JSBin or JSFiddle

Comment: I'm not very used to JSBin or JSFiddle, but I will try. By the way, I want to read a kendo hierarchical grid & carry both the master & child data to the server through ajax call. I'll try to put it into JSBin.

Comment: Hi, For master grid have a change="OnChange" in this event you will get the master grid's row details once you open the hierarchy and when you submit the child grids form in that event you can send Master Grids row details.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues are related to find `child grid datasource`

- Each master grid row contain a child grid
- Grid by default show single child grid

So if you try to find child grid, it always give you the expanded grids. Initially it give you single child grid. If you want all child grids you must expand all manually or programmatically.

See this [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/jU3HGmew9VKPcfNu4dDG?p=preview) here i render the child grid inside a `<div class="childGrid">`

```
function detailInit(e) {
  $('<div class="childGrid"></div>').appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      //others code
```

Then looping to get all the child grids `datasource`

```
$(".childGrid").each(function(index, element){
  console.log($(element).data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data());
});
```